# Scrape JSON Data

Tags: python, json, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape https://understat.com/team/Arsenal/2019 (and other EPL team pages) with BeautifulSoup4 to get links to all the player pages and eventually scrape those pages for individual player data, but have gotten stuck as I am unfamiliar with JSON data.

I've gotten as far as tracing to the part of the webpage which I'm interested in, but my current output looks like this `var playersData    = JSON.parse('\x5B\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22318\x22,\x22player_name\x22\x3A\x22Pierre\x2DEmerick\x20Aubameyang\x22,`...`,\x22xGBuildup\x22\x3A\x220\x22\x7D\x5D');`.

I can't find any information about JSON data in this format, and was wondering if someone would be able to help me get the data from this page into ideally the format of a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: They're just obfuscating the JSON by using hex codes for punctuation characters. `\x5B` is `[`, `\x7B` is `{`, `\x22` is `"`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those `\x` sequences are hex encodings of punctuation characters like `[`, `{`, and `"`, to obfuscate the JSON. Python uses the same notation in its string literals, so you can decode it with `ast.literal_eval()`.

```
import re
import ast
import json

line = r"var players_data = JSON.parse('\x5B\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22318\x22,\x22player_name\x22\x3A\x22Pierre\x2DEmerick\x20Aubameyang\x22,\x22xGBuildup\x22\x3A\x220\x22\x7D\x5D');"
literal = re.search(r"(?<=JSON\.parse\().*(?=\);$)", line).group(0)
json_string = ast.literal_eval(literal)
players_data = json.loads(json_string)
print(players_data)
```